# Dealing with roommate's taunting about mispronouncing vocabulary words

Tags: friends, teasing, taunts

I have a roommate who seems to enjoy taunting me over my mispronunciation of high vocabulary words, which is due to the fact that I don't usually hear people saying them, but rather learned them from reading.

We've only been roommates for two weeks, but this arrangement will likely continue for another year. How should I deal with this? Should I just put up with it and hope he gets over it eventually?

---

([Related Question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/589/52))

Comment: People usually are just what they are. How do you conclude it IS taunting? Can it not be this is just an abrasive personality doing what comes naturally? If that, just signalling the remark or the way the remark is made is unwelcome may be enough to stop the behaviour.

Comment: how is this 'related' and not just a duplicate?

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate. The original question was about "acquaintances" and implied one-off occurrences. This is about a roommate and continued hazing.

Comment: @Catija I agree. You can't just "ignore" them continuously. At some point, this has to stop.

Comment: They might think that they are doing a favour (I would love if someone corrects my pronunciation, as I will keep repeating my mistakes forever if that doesn't happen!), I think you need to work on two levels, one is to try to take that positively, and two is to tell them that you don't prefer this kind of correction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I occasionally have a similar issue with "reader's vocabulary," myself. It's certainly a problem.

I try, as much as I am able, to assume good intent when people correct my pronunciation of high-vocabulary words. Even though sometimes the correction may sound harsh (many times, because it's a quick word that can sound like a verbal jab), I've learned that most of the time, the corrector means well. As some of the commenters have already pointed out, would you really rather continue to mispronounce those words indefinitely? It's much better if the mistake is caught early on, before you use one of your "reader's vocabulary" words on an important job interview or the like.

It may be useful to try to mentally reframe your roommate's intent in this way. Even if you think that your roommate *does* include some unnecessary mockery in his corrections, you can "neutralize" it by smiling back and giving him a sincere "Thank you for that correction; I really appreciate that." will, ex post facto, force him to continue the conversation as if he did not intend any meanness at all. It will also make both of you look at future corrections in a more positive light.